# angularjs json data not loading through $httpBackend

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am making $http call from a service and responding with json data using $httpBackend. The load fails initially and below is the error message I get in the console. It works after I refresh the page few times.

```
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead jquery.min.js:1
Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
"Error: Unexpected request: GET lookup/program-categories
No more request expected
$httpBackend@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1179
sendReq@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:8181
$http/serverRequest@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:7921
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:11319
qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:11319
qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:11405
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:12412
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:12224
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:12516
done@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:8204
completeRequest@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:8412
createHttpBackend/</xhr.onreadystatechange@http://<hostname>.amazonaws.com/ostnfe/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:8355
"
```

Below is the code. The service 'lookups' makes the http call and the controller 'SearchCtrl' adds the values to the html scope.

```
var stubbedOstnApp = angular.module('stubbedOstnApp', [
  'ostnApp',
  'ngMockE2E'
]);

stubbedOstnApp.run(['$httpBackend','$http',function($httpBackend, $http){
    $http.get('../test/data/program-categories.json').then(function(data){
        $httpBackend.whenGET('lookup/program-categories').respond(data.data)
    });
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^views\//).passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\.\.\/test\/data\//).passThrough();
}]);



var ostnApp = angular.module('ostnApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ostnControllers'
]);


ostnApp.service('lookups',['$http',function($http){
    var programCategories = {};
    $http.get('lookup/program-categories').then(function(data){
        for(var i=0;i<data.data.length;i++){
            var programCategory = data.data[i];
            programCategory.selected = false;
            programCategories[programCategory.id] = programCategory;
        }
    });
    this.programCategories = function(){
        return programCategories;
    }
}]);


ostnControllers.controller('SearchCtrl',['$scope', '$http', 'lookups', function($scope, $http, lookups){
    //this gets displayed in the html
    $scope.programCategories = lookups.programCategories();

}]);
```

Comment: Try to move `$httpBackend` mock for `lookup/program-categories` out of the promise callback, if it works then it means that your service is called earlier then mock assigned.

Comment: If I move $httpBackend outside promise, it never works. The $httpBackend does not wait for the .then to complete and will respond with null data

Answer (score 0):

So, if moving of mock outside of the promise makes it to respond with `null` it means that your mock is not initialized when you are sending request. Try to preload it before running application to not wait for response and make mock immediately.

Comment: It'll be great if you can provide code samples for me to understand your response better.

Answer (score 0):

it seesm trying to access data without being fully loaded.
use under ngRoute the 'resolve' atribute to call to your service before loading the Controller.